# Reduce number of json files generated in Allure report to upload to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, webdriver-io, allure

I have an application which generates Allure reports from allure data created by webdriver.io using allure-commandline. The report is then uploaded to s3.

The problem is the millions of little json files in the report.

While uploading to s3, this means one PUT object request per file. My goal is to reduce the number of API calls made to s3.

There is no way to zip, upload and extract on s3 as s3 does not provide this service.

The only alternative I can think of is to somehow reduce the number of files generated in allure. Is this possible? Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable reporting iteraction wdio and selenium grid.
It will significantly decrease json files in the report.

See `disableWebdriverStepsReporting` in https://github.com/webdriverio/wdio-allure-reporter/#configuration

Comment: I tried this but there wasn't a major reduction in number of files. Most json files are generated in allure-report/data/attachments and allure-report/data/test-cases. I ended up using `mochawesome`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below config in your wdio.conf.js

This will generate only screenshots on failure. It worked for me with WDIO V4.14.2 and wdio-allure-reporter V 0.8.3

```
exports.config = {
....
...
 reporters: ['dot', 'allure'],
 reporterOptions: {
        outputDir: 'allure-results',
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
    },
....
....
}
```